# Porque o chr() é vulnerável ao ataque de "cache-timing" e o pack() não?

Tags: php, criptografia

Por curiosidade estou procurando e lento muitas coisas sobre criptografia e também procurando por algumas bibliotecas em PHP puro, como por exemplo o [Sodium_Compat](https://github.com/paragonie/sodium_compat), pelo único motivo de que entendo muito mais de PHP se comparado com C, *que é o ideal para criptografia, até onde eu saiba*.

Entretanto algo me chamou atenção no [seguinte trecho](https://github.com/paragonie/sodium_compat/blob/c665503bdce2ba1d1683b568f1c5f927986ad65c/src/Core/Util.php#L43-L75):

```
/**
* Use pack() and binary operators to turn the two integers
* into hexadecimal characters. We don't use chr() here, because
* it uses a lookup table internally and we want to avoid
* cache-timing side-channels.
*/
$hex .= pack(
'CC',
(55 + $b + ((($b - 10) >> 8) & ~6)),
(55 + $c + ((($c - 10) >> 8) & ~6))
);
```

Simplesmente não encontrei muitas informações sobre o `cache-timing`, lembrando que existe o `cache-timing attack` e o `timing attack`, que são coisas distintas (ou será que não?), o segundo possui mais informações.

Encontrei essa [informação aqui](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/41680/43380), que é a mais resumida e existe essa outra [reposta e comentário que parece ser quase a resposta desta pergunta](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34753/is-accessing-elements-of-an-array-in-secret-order-vulnerable-to-timing-attack), mas não tenho certeza. Inclusive baseado no comentário do código presumo que o problema seja que o `chr()` utiliza algum tipo de "array" (seria isso o `lookup table internally`?) enquanto o `pack()` não, porém como então o `pack()` é capaz de converter o inteiro para hexadecimal?

A questão é, o `pack()` supostamente não é vulnerável enquanto o `chr()` possui tal problema, *isto não é nem sequer mencionado na documentação do PHP, talvez por ser algo muito especifico*. O que as funções, por dentro, tem de diferente? Como eles convertem os números inteiros e por qual razão um consegue converter "de maneira mais segura que a outra"? Porque motivo ambos não são vulneráveis?

Comment: Não sei muito de criptografia (é algo que está na minha lista para estudar à tempos), mas acredito que sim, a `LUT internally` é basicamente um array, semelhante à própria tabela ASCII. Pelos comentários, a função evitar usar a LUT justamente para deixar a função mais lenta, ou seja, levar mais tempo para computá-la. Acredito que isso seja bastante útil contra ataques *Brute-force attack*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A implementação da função `pack()` é muito mais robusta em relação a função `chr()`.

Possui sanitizações e validações diversas, dentre elas, o [RFC 4648 Encoding](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4648.txt)

Um trecho das rotinas da função pack() onde os valores de entrada são filtrados:

```
static void php_pack(zval *val, size_t size, int *map, char *output)
{
    size_t i;
    char *v;

    convert_to_long_ex(val);
    v = (char *) &Z_LVAL_P(val);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        *output++ = v[map[i]];
    }
}
```

PHP-src: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/pack.c

AS funções como `ord()` e `chr()`, não tem muito o que comentar. Basta ver como a simplória implementação não possui filtros como na função `pack()`:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(ord)
{
    char   *str;
    size_t str_len;

    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_START(1, 1)
        Z_PARAM_STRING(str, str_len)
    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_END();

    RETURN_LONG((unsigned char) str[0]);
}
/* }}} */


PHP_FUNCTION(chr)
{
    zend_long c;

    if (ZEND_NUM_ARGS() != 1) {
        WRONG_PARAM_COUNT;
    }

    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_START_EX(ZEND_PARSE_PARAMS_QUIET, 1, 1)
        Z_PARAM_LONG(c)
    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_END_EX(c = 0);

    c &= 0xff;
    if (CG(one_char_string)[c]) {
        ZVAL_INTERNED_STR(return_value, CG(one_char_string)[c]);
    } else {
        ZVAL_NEW_STR(return_value, zend_string_alloc(1, 0));
        Z_STRVAL_P(return_value)[0] = (char)c;
        Z_STRVAL_P(return_value)[1] = '\0';
    }
}
```

PHP-src: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/string.c

Isso é simples dessa forma por questões de performance pois nem sempre precisa-se filtrar. Os filtros são mais indicados para o emprego de rotinas de criptografia, segurança, etc.

## Table look-ups

> Inclusive baseado no comentário do código presumo que o problema seja
> que o chr() utiliza algum tipo de "array" (seria isso o lookup table
> internally?)

Sim, isso é como a maioria das linguagens de programação utilizam em suas funções de manipulação de strings.

O método por "table look-ups" possui exploits conhecidos e são muito explorados por ataques. Uma proposta de solução é usar operações lógicas de sequências de "constant-time" (RFC 4648) ou pelo menos por referências que não sejam dos dados chave secretos (secret data).
Essa questão, no momento, está em discussão aberta, sem uma definição concreta.

Answer (score 2):

Quando se trata de criptografia existem diversos aspectos que devem ser levados em consideração.

O fato de se usar `pack()` em vez de `char()` refere-se a um conceito chamado binary safe fazendo com que tanto o input e output sejam consistentes em termos de manipulação de string por exemplo.

E como já dito anteriormente em uma das respostas que você pesquisou, dependendo de como é feito a criptografia e do algoritmo existe a possibilidade de identificar o modo e talvez funções utilizadas para se criptografar através do comportamento e explorar uma determinada vulnerabilidade existente.